# How do I see the affects of making a change to a CSS style

Tags: css

I have been asked by a friend to take a look at their mobile site, as a certain part is not displaying correctly.
I have found that inside of a certain div, any link is not displaying. Using Firefox, I can see that the following is in play:

```
.panel-content a{display:none}
```

Now, I am no CSS expert and the client doesn't have a test system. Rather than changing css elements on the fly, is there a method (or a program) that you can use to perhaps scan a site and see what this change would affect?

Answer (score 2):

Most browser allow you to explore the source code and experiment with some simple changes.

For example in Chrome you can pts F12 to shore the developer tools.

Our just right click on the element you want to explore and click on "inspect element".

Comment: Thanks for that. I know how to use the developer tools, however I'm wandering if there is a program that can show me the whole site what parts of the whole site will be affected, and not just a single page. Or perhaps a function where you can search a single page that will use the css rule

Comment: For that I use the plain text search of Eclipse. I'm afraid there are no tools that can keep in account all the ways a css rule can affect a page, especially if you use JQuery or other ways to make dynamic changes.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, there are emulation tools built in for mobile devices. If you open the Developer Tools (View > Developer > Developer Tools), look all the way to the top left corner of the new panel and you will see a magnifying glass, then a phone. Click the phone. You can chose from a bunch of different settings. Hope this helps.